# Как в React правильно обрабатывать redirect с сервера?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Сейчас делаю это так:

```
function updateProfile(url, data) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch(startUpdate());
        return fetch('/api'+url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
        }).then((res) => {
            dispatch(finishUpdate());
            if (res.redirected) {
                location.href = res.url;
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема вашего решения в том, что вы перезагружаете страницу вызывая `location.href = res.url;`.
Можно использовать [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) и с помощью `this.props.history.push(res.url)` отправлять на нужную страницу без полной перезагрузки.